# I installed tensorflow on mac and now I can't open Anaconda

Tags: python, macos, tensorflow, terminal, anaconda

I installed tensorflow on my mac and now I can't seem to open anaconda-navigator. When I launch the app, it appears in the dock but disappears quickly. When I launch anaconda-navigator the terminal I get the following error(s).

KeyError: 'pip._vendor.urllib3.contrib'

Answer (score 0):

I once had the same issue and fixed it by deleting the system pip cache.

Check https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5079 for more info.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by downgrading to pip version 9.0.1. It appears anaconda doesn't like pip version 9.0.2 I ran: pip install pip==9.0.1

Comment: This is indeed a breaking change for a lot of Anaconda users. See this (heated) GH issue https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5081